# Creating an Android app on facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I am sorry for this stupid question, but I simply do not find the answer:

Where do I enter the website on https://developers.facebook.com/apps ?

I cannot find it on the page settings, nor the page details.

Theree are enough how-to's on the Internet, but Facebook seems to change the UI frequently.

Thank you

Peter

Answer (score 0):

Click on "Add a new app" on top, then select Android.

[image]

Comment: I was able to add the app, with name, namespace etc. It is just the homepage that I cannot enter.

Comment: You mean the settings for the app? Or what homepage are you looking for?

Comment: Right. I mean the page with the left menu "Dashboard", "Settings", "Status & Reviews" and so on. The app cannot log in without a homepage. In Basic4android it is done like this: fb.Initialize(Activity, Me, "myFB", Main.AppID, Main.AppSecret, Main.myWebsite). the last variable is essential.

Comment: OK, I think now I get your question. In App Details you can add contact info, such as e.g. the Terms of Service URL which is probably what you need for the login...